# How to run a VM in gcp in the background?

Tags: python, linux, google-cloud-platform, debian, virtual-machine

I have a gcp linux VM, very basic question: If I have a simple script like this:

```
import time
for a in range (0,1000):
    print(a)
    time.sleep(10)
```

when I enter the console via ssh in browser connection I run the script, but it stops when I close the window.
How do I make it run even when I shut down my PC?

Comment: Use the Linux program **screen** to continue your **user session** in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nohup.

For example:

```
nohup python myscript.py &
```

And then you may close the session. The script will keep running on the remote VM, til it finishes.